# Duda en consulta con PHP (PDO) y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo una duda con una consulta realizada desde un PHP con PDO hacia una base de datos MySQL que no consigo resolver

La consulta que intento hacer es para que me devuelva de las Apps que el usuario quiere ($apps_id_a) solo las que no estén ya asignadas a su cuenta en la base de datos, pero solo he conseguido que me devuelva las Apps que ya están asignadas a su cuenta y el usuario no quiere (es decir, que no están en $apps_id_a)

```php
     /**
     * @param  string $user_id User ID
     * @param  array $apps_id_a Apps ID Array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function checkAsignableApps(string $user_id, array $apps_id_a): array
    {
        try {
            /* Crear una cadena para los parámetros de sustitución rellenados con el número de parámetros */
            $place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($apps_id_a), '?'));
            // var_dump($apps_id);  string(3) "4,5" (Ejemplo)
            $sql = "SELECT r.id, r.name FROM ".$this->tbl_user_apps." mr
                  INNER JOIN ".$this->tbl_apps." r on mr.app_id = r.id
                  INNER JOIN ".$this->tbl_members." m on mr.member_id = m.id
                  WHERE m.id = ? AND r.id NOT IN ($place_holders)";

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            array_unshift($apps_id_a, $user_id);
            $stmt->execute($apps_id_a);
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            $result['status'] = false;
            $result['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Aquí pueden ver la estructura de mi base de datos
[image: Estructura de la base de datos]

¿Como se haría para que la consulta devuelva de las Apps que el usuario quiere ($apps_id_a) solo las que no estén ya asignadas a su cuenta en la base de datos?

Comment: No entiendo por qué no eliminan la pregunta mejor

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor no generes más trabajo a los otros usuarios vandalizando tu publicación. Publicando en la red [SE] otorgaste derechos no revocables, bajo la [licencia CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) para que SE pueda distribuir su contenido. Por política de SE, cualquier clase de vandalismo será revertido. Si queres saber más sobre cómo eliminar una publicación, considera mirar: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/).

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

intenta utilizando left join en vez de inner join y en el where podrias checar las que esten en null

ejemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT r.id, r.name FROM ".$this->tbl_user_apps." mr
                  LEFT JOIN ".$this->tbl_apps." r on mr.app_id = r.id
                  LEFT JOIN ".$this->tbl_members." m on mr.member_id = m.id
                  WHERE m.id = ? AND r.id NOT IN ($place_holders) AND r.id is null";
```